# Run Webpack Dev Server programatically and wait for bundle to finish

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to do something which I feel is very simple, yet the internet cannot give me a simple answer.

I want to run Webpack Dev Server programmatically. I want to wait for the bundle to finish BEFORE I call listen.

Here is some code.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const config = require('./webpack.config');

const compiler = webpack(config);

const server = new WebpackDevServer(options, compiler);

// Wait here. I can do a promise, I can do just about anything. I JUST want to wait here.

return {
   start: () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         server.listen(port, 'localhost', async (err) => {
            if (err) {
               reject(err)
    
               return;
            }

            resolve();
         });
      });
   }
};
```

There has to be a way to have a simple callback from the compiler that says if it was successful or not. Maybe something from the dev server indicating it is ready and there were no bundling issues.

I have seen a LOT about jacking into plugins. TBH I did not understand and it all looked jenky at best.

If that is my only option can/will someone please explains to be the various parts of the what is going on when you "tap" into something. I'm sorry to the Webpack team, but the documentation could be better.

Also I could NOT find any information on running the compiler or the dev server programmatically. What I have above is what I have cobbled together from what I have found only from various online posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do do this but here is what I ended up doing.

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import WebpackDevServer from 'webpack-dev-server';
import Promise from 'bluebird';

const compiler = webpack(config);

const server = new WebpackDevServer(options, compiler);

await Promise.fromCallback((cb) => {
    server.listen(port, 'localhost', cb);
});

await Promise.fromCallback((cb) => {
    server.middleware.waitUntilValid((stats) => {
       if (stats.hasErrors()) {
           cb(stats.compilation.getErrors());
        } else {
            cb();
        }
    });
});
```

I got here by finding that the middleware allows to wait until valid. Valid is a terrible word here. In this context Valid means "done". If you want to know if the bundling was successful you need to check if the stats params "hasErrors()".

The dev server does not initialize the middleware until the server is started. So you have to start it first THEN access the middleware and it's waitUntilValid callback.